# Mysqli_init stops the script execution unexpected

Tags: php, mysql, apache, mysqli

I have a php5 script, it runs well, before this line:

```
echo "Hello world...";
$mysqli = mysqli_init();
echo "Mysql is ready...";
```

The output is: Hello world...

I don't get any error, any message, simply the script execution stops unexpectedly.
I use Ubuntu with PHP5 and Apache2 and Mysql 5.5

Thanks.

Comment: if it dies with no output, then you've got error_reporting and display_errors turned off. While developing/testing, they should NEVER be off in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

```
ini_set('display_errors', true );
error_reporting( E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE );
```